# Debug different language/locale Android app on my phone

Tags: android, android-studio, localization, galaxy

I created an Android app where all my strings are used as resources.
I added strings.xml in values-es folder and added all the strings in Spanish.
I changed my phone language to Spanish and ran the application from the Android Studio (my phone is connected via USB - Samsung Galaxy 3).
The app still shows the strings in English even though my phone language is Spanish.
I tried to reboot the phone and it didn't help.
Will appreciate any assistance.
Thanks

Comment: Do the labels refer to valid keys in the strings xml, like "@string/key_value_hello"? So it's not hardcoded strings? And when you inspect the value for Locale.getDefault().getLanguage() in logcat, what does it say?

Comment: Or check value like this Locale.getDefault().toString()

Answer (score 1):

There are couple types of Spanish languages (US, regular Spanish and etc..) and I checked the wrong one.
Changing the language in the phone is enough and works fine.